# Can PowerShell use a local assembly with a different version in the GAC?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell, dll, gac

I need to reference `System.Net.Http.dll` version 2.2.29.0 in a PowerShell script. The GAC has `System.Net.Http` version 4.0.0.0. Is it possible to redirect to my local DLL without modifying the GAC?

I've tried:

1. Adding the DLL through `Add-Type -Path 'System.Net.Http.dll'`.
2. Creating a .config file with an `<assemblyBinding>` element, like what .NET applications use for binding redirects.
3. Loading the DLL through `[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFrom("$PSScriptRoot\System.Net.Http.dll")`.

In all cases, subsequently executing `[AppDomain]::CurrentDomain.GetAssemblies()` shows that version 4.0.0.0 in `C:\Windows` is still the only copy loaded.

Comment: Can you show us the assemblyBinding config?

Comment: Did you try `[Reflection.Assembly]::LoadFile()`? Or did you try specifying the full path to the file when using `Add-Type`?

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen This is part of a C# class library project, so Visual Studio generated the config. I put it in the script folder with the DLL. But I now see PowerShell only considers bindings in `C:\Windows\(System32|SysWOW64)\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe.config`. As this needs to be done without GAC/machine-level modifications, it still isn't a viable option, but at least I see why the config was ignored now.

Comment: @EricEskildsen If you run the script from within your own application/library (via `System.Management.Automation`), you can apply the binding to just that

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen That could work. The script is for a bundle already deployed to multiple clients, but I could change the bundle's main script to start the C# app, then exit, and then have the C# app kick off the scripts. Even so, curious if there's a PowerShell-only solution to the general problem.

Comment: @TheMadTechnician Yes, tried with `LoadFile` and full path for `Add-Type`, but same result.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using the full name of the assembly? Version number included?

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName "Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91"
```

alternatively:

```
[reflection.assembly]::Load(“Microsoft.SqlServer.SMO, Version=11.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89845dcd8080cc91”)
```

hope this helps